# Time Zone Conversion in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have the following line in an eloquent query:

```
->whereBetween('issue_date', [$fiscal_start, $fiscal_end])
```

`$fiscal_start` and `$fiscal_end` are in the user's local time zone, and `issue_date` is (in the table) stored in UTC. All three are timestamps.

`$fiscal_start` example:

```
Carbon {#639 ▼
  +"date": "2016-07-01 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Australia/Sydney"
}
```

`$orgTz` contains `"Australia/Sydney"`

What is the correct syntax for converting the `issue_date` in the `whereBetween` statement to local timezone before comparison?

I have tried a few variations of this unsuccessfully:

```
->whereRaw("CONVERT_TZ(issue_date, 'UTC', {$orgTz}) BETWEEN {$fiscal_start} AND {$fiscal_end}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I was missing a couple of `'`

```
->whereRaw("CONVERT_TZ(issue_date, 'UTC', '{$orgTz}') BETWEEN '{$fiscal_start}' AND '{$fiscal_end}'")
```